# How to install pre-compiled Gaussian16 (Rev.A.03) and blurred font of GaussView6 on ARM Mac

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, gaussian, apple-operating-system

I wish to know whether someone here was able to install Gaussian16 on Mac computer with ARM processor? According to the instructions, UNIX environment variables shall be added either to tcsh or bash shell UNIX files. On M1/M2 Macs, however, ZSH is default one. I know that .zshenv equivalent to .bash_profile, but the variables installation instruction tells to export are taken from the Gaussian-written g16.login (tcsh) or g16.profile (bash) files, so they won't import to ZSH.

Regarding th second part of the question. I managed to install just Gaussian Utilities and run GaussView6. Unfortunately, I find all the text to be blurred. This is very unpleasant feeling, exhausting for longer time work, and while in the previous MacOS versions there was an option to turn off font smoothing, it is no more in MacOS Monterey (in any other program the font is perfectly fine!)

I have sent email to Gaussian Inc. few weeks ago but still no answer...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For just the installation process, can you switch your shell to bash. While zsh is the new default on Mac, bash (and tcsh) should still be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to change shell to bash for the installation and then, if one wants, may return to zsh. I did and this didn't affect G16. It is still working.
Regarding blurred font, I forward answer from reddit user geoffth2016:

> This is because GaussView is not set to run in high resolution. So macOS is doing its best to display a low-resolution font. Naturally that's blurry on your high-dpi screen. In the Finder, go to the app, right-click or control-click to bring up "Show Package Contents". Go into the Contents folder and there should be an "Info.plist" file. You can open this in Xcode or any text editor (probably easier). There should be a bunch of properties, like: (This is for Avogadro, not GaussView, but they should be very similar.)

```
        <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
        <string>10.8.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Avogadro</string>
```

> You want to add:

```
        <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
        <string>True</string>
```

> You should now get high-resolution fonts.